# unmarshaling xml with multiple representations for same element

Tags: java, jaxb, jersey

I need to unmarshall some data from xml (from Redmine web services).

The problem is that the data is represented as attributes when nested in other elements: see 'project' here...

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<issues type="array" count="1640">
  <issue>
    <id>4326</id>
    <project name="Redmine" id="1"/>
    <!-- ... ->
  </issue>
</issues>
```

But the same project data is represented as elements if I try to get a list of projects:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<projects type="array">
  <project>
    <id>1</id>
    <name>Redmine</name>
    <identifier>redmine</identifier>
    <created_on>Sat Sep 29 12:03:04 +0200 2007</created_on>
    <!-- ... ->
  </project>
</projects>
```

What's the most simple way to do it with JAXB (standard if possible)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that there are multiple, slightly different mappings.

I ended up making different classes with different annotations.

EDIT: another way: http://blog.bdoughan.com/2011/09/mapping-objects-to-multiple-xml-schemas.html (but not type-safe and outside of standard jaxb, I'll leave my current implementation as-is).

Answer (score -2):

If you have the schema of the XML. You could try to use JAXB. JAXB will give you an object representation of your XML. Use a visitor to extract every occurrence of a project.

JAXB is standard within any JDK since 1.5 or 1.6.

Comment: I don't have the schema. There probably isn't any: if there was one, xml representation would be consistent. I do have java classes that I want to map to (hand-coded / copied), but lacking some JAXB annotations. That's what I'm asking for.

Comment: Updated the question to reflect that I want to do it with JAXB, although it's already tagged as such.

Comment: Do you mean that the two XML snippets come from the same XML file?

Comment: 2 methods of the same web service (Redmine).

Comment: Those two methods give an answer that could be seen as two separate XML files. Right? If yes, those two answers will conform themselves to two different schemas. You might not have those schemas but they exist.

Comment: They don't. Checked redmine, they write xml elements and attribute with dumb print commands. Basically, each output can have a different schema. And does, somehow. Anyway, I had to solve it with different classes, used depending on context.

Comment: They don't have a schema but you can create a schema that will match the web service's response. The annoying things: 1) It's kind of reverse engineering. 2) It might changes over the time. 3) You might need a schema per web service (as far as I see at least two!).

Comment: Thanks, this is just what I did. The problem is that there are multiple, slightly different mappings. I ended up making different classes with different annotations.